# Dell e6530 wireless keeps disconnecting on Windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-latitude, broadcom, 802.11

I have a Dell e6530 64 Bit with Windows 8.1 and about every 20 Minutes my wireless disconnects even though I am in the same room as the router.

I have full signal strength and my colleage does not have any problems with it. I first used the Microsoft driver, then the one from Broadcom and now “Dell Wireless 1504 802.11b/g/n (2,4 GHz)” which the Dell website presents me after a system check and the problem persists. I have read much advice and following it disabled all wireless power management and energy saving features and disabled or deinstalled all other network devices except the LAN driver.

The event viewer doesn't show me anything and the device in the device manager does not have a question mark attached.

I have a shown transfer rate of 39.0 MBit/s or 52.0 MBit/s (varies while connected), 5/5 bars signal strength and the connection uses WPA2-Personal with AES encryption.

I have been testing it with Arch Linux right now. `lspci` reports it as `02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`. And after testing it for nearly an hour now on Linux, no disconnects, no `dmesg` message.

`iwconfig` reports the following, I don't know if that is 802.11b, g or n.

```
wlp2s0
      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"[...]"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: [...]   
      Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:196  Invalid misc:175   Missed beacon:0
```

As suggested by @Giacomo1968, I set it to g mode (Configure->Advanced->BSS-Mode "802.11g-Mode") and it is running for over an hour right now, I will report back after longer testing.

Update: Now more disconnects for days, accepting the answer, thank you very much, Jake!

Comment: Does it behave the same way on other WiFi networks? When it acts up, does it actually show that it's disconnected, or does the network just stop working?

Comment: I only have this one network here so I don't know about others. Some times it shows that it has problems with a yellow marker and says the connection is limited, other times it displays as always but it never shows a disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of Wi-Fi are you actually connecting at?  You mention 802.11b/g/n in the question, but are you connected at 802.11g? Or 802.11n?

While I am not a Windows expert, I do believe the issue is the Windows drivers choking on 802.11n negotiation because honestly 802.11n implementation is somewhat of a mess from my experience. I would recommend forcing a connection at 802.11g to see what happens. It might be worth it to try reinstalling the Wi-Fi drivers for that adapter to see what happens. But it all points to a driver issue from what I am reading.

Comment: I added `iwconfig`output, but I don't know what type it is, I guess n because of the 65 MB/s. I will try forcing it down in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try a fresh driver from Lenovo "Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter 7.12.39.11":
http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-75//downloads/DS100424 
unzip and select: WLAN Driver (Atheros, Realtek, Broadcom, Intel)\Broadcom\7.12.39.11\Driver\Win8.1\bcmwl63.inf

This solution works for my Dell Latitude 6430u on Windows 8.1 with card "dell wireless 1504 802.11b/g/n". With this driver you can use "n" mode without disconnecting.

Comment: Driver for Windows 10 (64-bit): http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-75/downloads/DS103990

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to install the Lenovo drivers listed in other answers for this question on my Dell Inspiron 6530. I found the correct Windows 10 driver for my Dell Inspiron 6530 here:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=V1TCK

(As an aside, I tried entering this as a comment, but because I have less than 50 reputation points, the system wouldn't let me. Hence, the "answer".)